# Minecraft modding 1.12 - texture not showing

Tags: java, compiler-errors, minecraft-forge

I need help figuring out what the problem is. I'm not good at reading error messages and simply cannot solve it. I've looked all over the internet but nothing seems to help, always the same error messages.

I think it has something to do when its loading/registering the model.

There are also error messages further up about not able to read a class, theres an illegalArgumentException: Null.

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

````
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model adventurealot:item/nether_scythe with loader VanillaLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:161) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:302) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:151) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: adventurealot:models/item/nether_scythe.json
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:69) ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModel(ModelBakery.java:334) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.access$1400(ModelLoader.java:115) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:861) ~[ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:157) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 20 more
[13:49:28] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant adventurealot:nether_scythe#inventory for item "adventurealot:nether_scythe", blockstate location exception: 
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model adventurealot:nether_scythe#inventory with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:161) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:296) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:151) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29) [legacydev-0.2.3.1-fatjar.jar:0.2.3.1+4+372be23]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:83) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1175) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:157) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 20 more```
````

Comment: do you understand what 'FileNotFound' means? aused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: adventurealot:models/item/nether_scythe.json

Comment: that it doesnt find a certain file?